# TYPO3 Solr: How to add additional fields to indexer?

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-8.x

[TYPO3 8.7, ext_solr 9.0]

I have a custom extension for events. Solr should index the field `startdate` but doesn't. Everything else works fine.

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue {
    events = 1
    events {
        table = tx_customevents_domain_model_event
        fields {
            title = title
            abstract = teaser
            startdate_intS = startdate
            content = SOLR_CONTENT
            content {
                field = bodytext
            }
            url = TEXT
            url {
                typolink {
                    parameter =  {$plugin.tx_customevents_list.settings.singelePid}
                    additionalParams = &tx_customevents_list[event]={field:uid}&tx_customevents_list[action]=show&tx_customevents_list[controller]=Event
                    additionalParams.insertData = 1
                    returnLast = url
                    useCacheHash = 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
plugin.tx_solr.search.query.queryFields := addToList(startdate_intS^1.0)
```

The Fluid debugger does not show it in the `resultSet` object, even after having emptied the index queue.

What am I missing here?

Comment: don't forget: the TYPO3 field `startdate` has the type `unixtime` instead of (mysql)`date`.

Comment: Thank you. After changing startdate_dateS to startdate_intS the new custom field shows up in the list of Index Fields. But still it is not accessible in `resultSet`

Comment: do a debug on {document.startdate_dateS} and be sure that this record you are testing really got this field and not some other record

Comment: You probably meant <f:debug>{document.fields.startdate_intS}</f:debug>. The result shown is "NULL".

Comment: I would check the solr server directly about the documents. if that is not possible I would suggest dropping the index and rebuilding it, just to be sure that the field is set on all records and no, the `fields.`is *not* required, document.fieldname is fine